# Есть ли такое слово "простилалось"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Везде и всюду оно подчёркивается красной волнистой линией как ошибка. Гугл предлагает заменить его на **простиралось**. Значение именно слова **простилалось** я найти не могу, но тот же Гугл выдаёт множество вариантов, где оно используется. В основном это самиздат с авторской пунктуацией и, следовательно, орфографией. Что касается значения слова, нашла [вот это](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), но не знаю, считается ли данный ресурс авторитетным источником:

> **Значение** 
>   *стлать* вдоль чего-либо или по всей поверхности, прокладывать, перекладывать слоем
>   чего-либо

Но в этом случае непонятно, если слово есть, то, возможно, нет такой его формы?
С **простираться** всё понятнее:

> **Значение** распространяться по какому-либо пространству; занимать какое-либо пространство

Собственно, практически одно и то же, нет?

Приведу примеры:
*Вокруг простилалось болото, рядом протекала река, и над головой клубилась багровая река энергии — недоброй нужно сказать энергии, от которой мороз шёл по коже.*
Юрий Ландарь, Наследие титанов, 2013; *Местность вокруг была менее лесистой, проще говоря, вокруг простиралась болотистая равнина, но сама деревня была красивой и обсаженной деревьями.* Г. М. Кружков, Очерки по истории английской поэзии. Романтики и викторианцы. Том 2, 2015 **(то же болото, но в одном предложении оно простилается, а в другом простирается).**

P.S. Нашла [упоминание](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/230897/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F): ПРОСТИЛАТЬСЯ — ПРОСТИЛАТЬСЯ, простилаюсь, простилаешься, несовер. страд. к простилать (см. простлать в 1 знач.). Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940

Так что же получается? Оба варианта существуют и имеют схожее значение? Или это такая распространённая ошибка?

Comment: думаю, это тоже самое что и слово простиралась, точнее последнее произошло от простилалась путем замены л на р (одной сонорной на другую, подобную, видимо чтобы не перетягивала Р в приставке пРо-). Вообще Р и Л звуки, как это ни странно парные, в японском Л отсутствует и все Л заменяются на Р - Р это как грубое или твёрдое Л.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд, в первом литературном примере слово употреблено не совсем удачно: можно поискать оправдание в значении "стелиться", "*про*легая" как-нибудь фигурно и находя пути, чтобы "простелиться" между деревьями и т. п., однако в сочетании с "вокруг" или "повсюду" можно только бескрайне "прости**р**аться". В лучшем случае это ответственность корректора. А само слово "простилаться" со значением "*стелить(ся) **вдоль (в направлении)***" есть также в толковом словаре Ефремовой (википедия оттуда и взяла толкование), в форме глагола "простилать". Хотя оно и малоупотребительно, можно себе представить его возвратную форму несов. вида (простилаться) и употребление в страдательном залоге (простилаться кем-то):

> Красная дорожка всегда простилалась специально обученными людьми.

Comment: Мне тоже показалось, что в первом варианте **простилалось** выбрано неудачно, простилаться больше свойственно, скажем, туману, нежели болоту. Что касается его формы (возвратная форма несов. вида, как вы сказали) — это-то меня и смущало, я решила, что оно в этой форме не употребляется вовсе, раз его так непросто найти.